# What is an EJB, and what does it do?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1

Been trying to learn what `EJB` beans are, what does it mean their instances are managed in a pool, blah blah. Really can't get a good grip of them.

Can you explain me what they really are (practically for a Java Programmer)? What do they do? Which are their purposes? *Why really use them? (Why not just stick to `POJO`?)* Perhaps an example application?

Please refer only to updated information, that is `EJB 3.1`. Dated information about EJB can be misleading.

For EJB learning beginners please note:

EJB are based on **distributed objects**, this refer to software pieces running on multiple machines (virtual or physical) linked by a **network**.

Comment: Related: [When is it necessary or convenient to use Spring or EJB3 or all of them together?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18369356)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

> *Why really use them? (Why not just stick to POJO?)*

IF you need a component that accesses the database, or accesses other connectivity/ directory resources, or is accessed from multiple clients, or is intended as a SOA service, EJBs today are usually "bigger, stronger, faster (or at least more scalable) and simpler" than POJOs.  They are most valuable for servicing large numbers of users over the web or corporate network and somewhat less valuable for small apps within a department.

1. Reusing/Sharing Logic across multiple applications/clients with Loose Coupling.
   EJBs can be packaged in their own jars, deployed, and invoked from lots of places.
   They are common components.  True, POJOs can be (carefully!) designed as libraries and 
   packaged as jars.  But EJBs support both local and remote network access - including 
   via local java interface, transparent RMI, JMS async message and SOAP/REST web service,
   saving from cut-and-paste jar dependencies with multiple (inconsistent?) deployments.
   They are very useful for creating SOA services. When used for local access they are 
   POJOs (with free container services added). The act of designing a separate EJB layer 
   promotes extra care for maximizing encapsulation, loose coupling and cohesion, and 
   promotes a clean interface (Facade), shielding callers from complex processing & data 
   models.
2. Scalability and Reliability 
   If you apply a massive number of requests from various calling messages/processes
   /threads, they are distributed across the available EJB instances in the pool first 
   and then queued.  This means that if the number of incoming requests per second is 
   greater than the server can handle, we degrade gracefully - there are always some 
   requests being processed efficiently and the excess requests are made to wait.  We 
   don't reach server "meltdown" - where ALL requests experience terrible response time 
   simultaneously, plus the server tries to access more resources than the hardware & OS 
   can handle & hence crashes.  EJBs can be deployed on separate tier that can be 
   clustered - this gives reliability via failover from one server to another, plus 
   hardware can be added to scale linearly.
3. Concurrency Management.
   The container ensures that EJB instances are automatically accessed safely (serially) 
   by multiple clients.  The container manages the EJB pool, the thread pool, the 
   invocation queue, and automatically carries out method-level write locking (default) or 
   read locking (through @Lock(READ)).  This protects data from corruption through 
   concurrent write-write clashes, and helps data to be read consistently by preventing 
   read-write clashes.
   This is mainly useful for @Singleton session beans, where the bean is manipulating and 
   sharing common state across client callers.  This can be easily over-ridden to manually 
   configure or programmatically control advanced scenarios for concurrent code execution 
   and data access.
4. Automated transaction handling.
   Do nothing at all and all your EJB methods are run 
   in a JTA transaction.  If you access a database using JPA or JDBC it is automatically 
   enlisted in the transaction.  Same for JMS and JCA invocations.  Specify 
   @TransactionAttribute(someTransactionMode) before a method to specify if/how that
   particular method partakes in the JTA transaction, overriding default mode: "Required".
5. Very simple resource/dependency access via injection.
   The container will lookup resources and set resource references as instance fields in 
   the EJB: such as JNDI stored JDBC connections, JMS connections/topics/queues, other 
   EJBs, JTA Transactions, JPA entity manager persistence contexts, JPA entity manager 
   factory persistence units, and JCA adaptor resources.
   e.g. to setup a reference to another EJB & a JTA Transaction & a JPA entity Manager & 
   a JMS connection factory and queue:

   ```
   @Stateless
   public class MyAccountsBean {

       @EJB SomeOtherBeanClass someOtherBean;
       @Resource UserTransaction jtaTx;
       @PersistenceContext(unitName="AccountsPU") EntityManager em;
       @Resource QueueConnectionFactory accountsJMSfactory;
       @Resource Queue accountPaymentDestinationQueue;

       public List<Account> processAccounts(DepartmentId id) {
           // Use all of above instance variables with no additional setup.
           // They automatically partake in a (server coordinated) JTA transaction
       }
   }
   ```

   A Servlet can call this bean locally, by simply declaring an instance variable:

   ```
   @EJB MyAccountsBean accountsBean;
   ```

   and then just calling its' methods as desired.
6. Smart interaction with JPA.
   By default, the EntityManager injected as above uses a transaction-scoped persistence 
   context.  This is perfect for stateless session beans.  When a (stateless) EJB method 
   is called, a new persistence context is created within the new transaction, all 
   entity object instances retrieved/written to the DB are visible only within that 
   method call and are isolated from other methods.  But if other stateless EJBs are 
   called by the method, the container propagates and shares the same PC to them, so same 
   entities are automatically shared in a consistent way through the PC in the same 
   transaction.
   If a @Stateful session bean is declared, equal smart affinity with JPA is achieved by 
   declaring the entityManager to be an extended scope one: 
   @PersistentContent(unitName="AccountsPU, type=EXTENDED).  This exists for the life of 
   the bean session, across multiple bean calls and transactions, caching in-memory copies 
   of DB entities previously retrieved/written so they do not need to be re-retrieved.
7. Life-Cycle Management.
   The lifecycle of EJBs is container managed.  As required, it creates EJB instances, 
   clears and initializes stateful session bean state, passivates & activates, and calls 
   lifecycle callback methods, so EJB code can participate in lifecycle operations to 
   acquire and release resources, or perform other initialization and shutdown behavior.
   It also captures all exceptions, logs them, rolls back transactions as required, and 
   throws new EJB exceptions or @ApplicationExceptions as required.
8. Security Management.
   Role-based access control to EJBs can be configured via a simple annotation or XML 
   setting.  The server automatically passes the authenticated user details along with each 
   call as security context (the calling principal and role).  It ensures that all RBAC 
   rules are automatically enforced so that methods cannot be illegally called by the 
   wrong role.  It allows EJBs to easily access user/role details for extra programmatic 
   checking.  It allows plugging in extra security processing (or even IAM tools) to the 
   container in a standard way.
9. Standardization & Portability.
   EJB implementations conform to Java EE standards and coding conventions, promoting quality 
   and ease of understanding and maintenance.  It also promotes portability of code to new 
   vendor app servers, by ensuring they all support the same standard features and 
   behaviors, and by discouraging developers from accidentally adopting proprietary
   non-portable vendor features.
10. The Real Kicker: Simplicity.    All of the above can be done with 
     very streamlined code - either using default settings     for EJBs 
     within Java EE 6, or adding a few annotations.  Coding 
     enterprise/industrial     strength features in your own POJOs would
     be *way* more volumous, complex and     error-prone.  Once you 
     start coding with EJBs, they are rather easy to develop and give a great set of "free ride" benefits.

In the original EJB spec of 10 years ago, EJBs were a major productivity hassle.  They were bloated, needed lots of code and configuration artifacts and provided about 2/3 of the benefits above.  Most web projects did not actually use them.  But this has changed significantly with 10 years of tweaking, overhauling, functional enhancement and development stream-lining.  In Java EE 6 they provide maximum level industrial strength and simplicity of use.

What's not to like?? :-)  :-)

Answer (score 71):

An EJB is a Java component, containing business logic, that you deploy in a container, and that benefits from technical services provided by the container, usually in a declarative way, thanks to annotations:

- transaction management: a transaction can be started automatically before a method of the EJB is invoked, and committed or rollbacked once this method returns. This transactional context is propagated to calls to other EJBs.
- security management: a check can be made that the caller has the necessary roles to execute the method.
- dependency injection: other EJBs, or resources like a JPA entity manager, a JDBC datasource, etc. can be injected into the EJB.
- concurrency: the container makes sure that only one thread at a time invokes a method of your EJB instance.
- distribution: some EJBs can be called remotely, from another JVM.
- failover and load-balancing: remote clients of your EJBs can automatically have their call redirected to another server if necessary.
- resource management: stateful beans can automatically be passivated to disk in order to limit the memory consumption of your server.
- ... I probably have forgotten some points.

Comment: When you refer to transaction - you refer to persistance?

Comment: Yes, but not only. EJB containers provide a distributed JTA transaction manager, supporting multiple resources in a single transaction. You could for example update some data in a database, and send some JMS messages, in a single transaction. If anything failed, everything would be rollbacked: the DB updates and the sent messages.

Comment: @JBNizet excuse me for commenting on an old thread, but NOT EJB frameworks like Spring are providing these services that you mentioned. i dont understand the difference

Comment: The basic principles are the same. Spring took ideas from EJBs and vice-versa. But the API, implementation, way to deploy, and some features are different.

Comment: @JB Nizet In MVC pattern, where would you place EJBs in general? I'd say they belong to Model layer, although I know many people who say they are controllers. If EJB contain business logic (you said they do), then they're model layer by definition.

Answer (score 21):

Hope this from Oracle doc will help someone like me to understand the topic of EJB in a simple way.

> What Is an Enterprise Bean?
>   Written in the Java programming language, an enterprise bean is a server-side component that encapsulates the business logic of an application. The business logic is the code that fulfills the purpose of the application. In an inventory control application, for example, the enterprise beans might implement the business logic in methods called checkInventoryLevel and orderProduct. By invoking these methods, clients can access the inventory services provided by the application.
>
> Benefits of Enterprise Beans For several reasons, enterprise beans
>   simplify the development of large, distributed applications. First,
>   because the EJB container provides system-level services to enterprise
>   beans, the bean developer can concentrate on solving business
>   problems. The EJB container, rather than the bean developer, is
>   responsible for system-level services such as transaction management
>   and security authorization.
>
> Second, because the beans rather than the clients contain the
>   application’s business logic, the client developer can focus on the
>   presentation of the client. The client developer does not have to code
>   the routines that implement business rules or access databases. As a
>   result, the clients are thinner, a benefit that is particularly
>   important for clients that run on small devices.
>
> Third, because enterprise beans are portable components, the
>   application assembler can build new applications from existing beans.
>   These applications can run on any compliant Java EE server provided
>   that they use the standard APIs.
>
> When to Use Enterprise Beans You should consider using enterprise
>   beans if your application has any of the following requirements:
>
> The application must be scalable. To accommodate a growing number of
>   users, you may need to distribute an application’s components across
>   multiple machines. Not only can the enterprise beans of an application
>   run on different machines, but also their location will remain
>   transparent to the clients.
>
> Transactions must ensure data integrity. Enterprise beans support
>   transactions, the mechanisms that manage the concurrent access of
>   shared objects.
>
> The application will have a variety of clients. With only a few lines
>   of code, remote clients can easily locate enterprise beans. These
>   clients can be thin, various, and numerous.

Answer (score 5):

The question that interests me most is how and where can I use them. To understand this, we need first to see what types of EJBs exist. There are 2 big categories:

1. Session beans
2. Message driven beans

Let's consider Session Beans. They are of 3 kinds:

1. **Stateful** - these components maintain state and are specific for a client across multiple requests. See it as a session. The immediate use these could be put to is **shop carts** or other type of sessions (login session and so on)
2. **Stateless** - these are self contained components that don't persist information between requests, but they are unique to the user. Immediate use that comes to mind - **Service classes in the service layer**. Imagine `OrderService`. Another big use for these is to expose web services. Again, this be in the Service layer or totally separate.
3. **Singleton** - these are the beans that exist per application and are created once and can be reused / accessed multiple times. Immediately the **`Configuration`** component comes to mind - where you can store application level configs and access them when you need them from anywhere.

Now the rest of the capabilities or features can be used across layers in any such situations:

- **Security** - you can check for permissions with an annotation on the method that is called. This can happen in the Service layer as well as in Controller if you wish so.
- **Transaction management** - this is the obvious candidate in the Service layer or Persistence layer
- **Dependency Injection** - again will be used everywhere

One big use in modern times are the so called Microservices and Service Oriented Architectures. You can package some business logic components as EJBs and distribute them across the organization, to be used by multiple clients (by client here I mean other back-end applications).

And so on. Now the big drawback is that you become very dependent on the EJB container and although you could switch between 2 reference implementations, you will not be able to switch to something lighter - Tomcat for example. But why would you want to sacrifice all the benefits?

Answer (score 0):

EJB are where the business logic goes in a tiered application.  following that model a tier (different from a layer) is independently accessible from the User and other interfaces, hence they can be deployed and accessed by multiple components with multiple protocols.

In the Normalized System Model, EJB are the "Actions" and "Workflows" while Servlets would be the "Interfaces", JCA the "Connectors" and Timers and JMS the "Events".