# When is it necessary or convenient to use Spring or EJB3 or all of them together?

Tags: spring, jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, service-layer

I'm a little confused by the mixed use of JSF2+Spring+EJB3 or any combination of those. I know one of the Spring principal characteristics is dependency injection, but with JSF managed beans I can use `@ManagedBean` and `@ManagedProperty` anotations and I get dependency injection functionality. With EJB3 I'm even more confused about when to use it along with JSF or if there is even a reason to use it.

So, in what kind of situation would it be a good idea to use Spring+JSF2 or EJB3+JSF2?

Until now I have created just some small web applications using only JSF2 and never needed to use Spring or EJB3. However, I'm seeing in a lot of places that people are working with all this stuff together.

Comment: Mainly, when you need transparent DB transaction management and/or when you get tired of all that JDBC boilerplate code. Note that Spring and EJB are competiting and usually not mixed together. Choose one or other. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011392/jsf-service-layer

Comment: thanks for your answer, in my projects i've used open JPA for the DB transaction management, what is the difference between using jpa or EJB?

Comment: EJB is part of JavaEE, which is a container provided by some app servers like JBoss or GlassFish. This server contain a JPA implementation themselves, as JavaEE containers. Also you can configure your JPA configuration in Spring, in this case providing an implementation yourself (which can be EclipseLink, Hibernate..)

Comment: Like JDBC, JPA has no automatic transaction management at all. You'd still need to manage it yourselves (`t = em.getTransaction()`, `t.begin()`, `t.commit()`, etc). JPA is not a transaction management API, but an ORM API.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

First of all, Spring and EJB(+JTA) are competing technologies and usually not to be used together in the same application. Choose the one or the other. Spring **or** EJB(+JTA). I won't tell you which to choose, I will only tell you a bit of history and the facts so that you can easier make the decision.

---

Main problem they're trying to solve is providing a business service layer API with automatic transaction management. Imagine that you need to fire multiple SQL queries to perform a single business task (e.g. placing an order), and one of them failed, then you would of course like that *everything* is rolled back, so that the DB is kept in the same state as it was before, as if completely nothing happened. If you didn't make use of transactions, then the DB would be left in an invalid state because the first bunch of the queries actually succeeded.

If you're familiar with basic JDBC, then you should know that this can be achieved by turning off autocommit on the connection, then firing those queries in sequence, then performing `commit()` in the very same `try` in whose `catch (SQLException)` a `rollback()` is performed. This is however quite [tedious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160756/in-jdbc-when-autocommit-is-false-and-no-explicit-savepoints-have-been-set-is-i/3161654#3161654) to implement everytime.

With Spring and EJB(+JTA), a single (stateless) business service method call counts by default transparently as a single full transaction. This way you don't need to worry about transaction management at all. You do not need to manually create `EntityManagerFactory`, nor explicitly call `em.getTransaction().begin()` and such as you would do when you're tight-coupling business service logic into a JSF backing bean class and/or are using `RESOURCE_LOCAL` instead of `JTA` in JPA. You could for example have just the following EJB class utilizing JPA:

```
@Stateless
public class OrderService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @EJB
    private ProductService productService;

    public void placeOrder(Order newOrder) {
        for (Product orderedproduct : newOrder.getProducts()) {
            productService.updateQuantity(orderedproduct);
        }

        em.persist(newOrder);
    }

}
```

If you have a `@EJB private OrderService orderService;` in your JSF backing bean and invoke the `orderService.placeOrder(newOrder);` in the action method, then a single full transaction will be performed. If for example one of the `updateQuantity()` calls or the `persist()` call failed with an exception, then it will rollback any so far executed `updateQuantity()` calls, and leave the DB in a clean and crisp state. Of course, you could catch that exception in your JSF backing bean and display a faces message or so.

Noted should be that "Spring" is a quite large framework which not only competes EJB, but also CDI and JPA. Previously, during the dark J2EE ages, when EJB 2.x was extremely terrible to implement (the above EJB 3.x `OrderService` example would in EJB 2.x require at least 5 times more code and some XML code). Spring offered a much better alternative which required less Java code (but still many XML code). J2EE/EJB2 learned the lessons from Spring and came with Java EE 5 which offers new EJB3 API which is even more slick than Spring and required no XML at all.

Spring also offers IoC/DI (inversion of control; dependency injection) out the box. This was during the J2EE era configured by XML which can go quite overboard. Nowadays Spring also uses annotations, but still some XML is required. Since Java EE 6, after having learned the lessons from Spring, CDI is offered out the box to provide the same DI functionality, but then without any need for XML. With Spring DI `@Component`/`@Autowired` and CDI `@Named`/`@Inject` you can achieve the same as JSF does with `@ManagedBean`/`@ManagedProperty`, but Spring DI and CDI offers many more advantages around it: you can for example write interceptors to pre-process or post-process managed bean creation/destroy or a managed bean method call, you can create custom scopes, producers and consumers, you can inject an instance of narrower scope in an instance of broader scope, etc.

Spring also offers MVC which essentially competes JSF. It makes no sense to mix JSF with Spring MVC. Further Spring also offers Data which is essentially an extra abstraction layer over JPA, further minimizing DAO boilerplate (but which essentially doesn't represent the business service layer as whole).

#### See also:

- [What exactly is Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee)
- [JSF Controller, Service and DAO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao/)
- [@Stateless beans versus @Stateful beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887140/jsf-request-scoped-bean-keeps-recreating-new-stateful-session-beans-on-every-req/8889612#8889612)

Answer (score 5):

There's no real easy answer here as Spring is many things.

On a really high level, Spring competes with Java EE, meaning you would use either one of them as a full stack framework.

On a finer grained level, the Spring IoC container and Spring Beans compete with the combination of CDI & EJB in Java EE.

As for the web layer, Spring MVC competes with JSF. Some Spring xyzTemplate competes with the JPA interfaces (both can use eg Hibernate as the implementation of those).

It's possible to mix and match; eg use CDI & EJB beans with Spring MVC, OR use Spring Beans with JSF.

You will normally not use 2 directly competing techs together. Spring beans + CDI + EJB in the same app, or Spring MVC + JSF is silly.