# Basic Setup for JSF with Apache

Tags: apache, jsf, tomcat

I'm currently working on a JSF project at work. But, I get everything preconfigured, all I have to do is hack my code.
I've been doing this for a few weeks now and I tasted blood using JSF. So to intensify my knowledge I want to build myself a setup which I can use at home to test, work and educate myself.
So what do I need, and what do I need to configure so everything works. Preferably I'd like to use Apache and Tomcat, but that's about as far as my knowledge goes. I do know, that I should have/need a framework like Spring, but what exactly is that for?

I'd appreciate the help
Thx!

Comment: Just start from scratch with help of a good JSF book/tutorial/resource. Start at our JSF wiki page: hover the `[jsf]` tag which you placed on the question and then click *info* link in the popbox. As to Spring, this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369356/when-is-it-necessary-or-convenient-to-use-springjsf2-or-ejb3jsf2-or-all-of-the

Comment: Thanks a lot @BalusC . This is pretty much what I've been looking for thanks! You seem to be the JSF guru around here ;) As for the book.. any recommendations?

Comment: The JSF wiki page thus.