# Is PersistenceContext allowed in RequestScoped bean?

Tags: ejb, jax-rs, cdi, jta

With following class,

```java
@Path("/somes")
@RequestScoped
public class SomesResource {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "some")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Inject
    private SomeService someService;
}
```

Where,

```java
@Stateless
public class SomeService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "some")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

- Question 1: Is it O.K. to be injected with `@PersistenceContext` in `@RequestScoped` bean?
- Question 2: Is `entityManager` in `SomesResource` need to be worked with an `UserTransaction` in any modification job?
- Question 3: Are two `entityManager`s effectively same instance?

Comment: You already gave answer yourself in 2nd question. A backing bean has no automatic transaction management while an enterprise bean has (i.e. no need to fiddle with `UserTransaction` mess). That's the key difference. Apparently you didn't exactly understand why EJBs exist. This is then food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369356/when-is-it-necessary-or-convenient-to-use-springjsf2-or-ejb3jsf2-or-all-of-the

Comment: Java EE 7 specifies a transaction interceptor that you can use to enable transactions in CDI beans.