# UserDAOImpl and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, dao

I write my project on Servlet and Hibernate. This is example of my source code:

```
@Override
    public Long insertUser(User user) throws HibernateException {
        Long id;
        try{
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            id = (Long) session.save(user);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }finally{
            if(session != null && session.isOpen())
                session.close();
        }

        return id;
    }
```

I have a question, i often write the same code:

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

session.getTransaction().commit();

if(session != null && session.isOpen())
session.close();
```

I think that this is very strange. Do you know solution for simplify code?

Comment: As far as my experience goes you have to write either at minimum  Session s =  this.session.getCurrentSession();. For that you need to autowire session via your spring config file. Also you need to do the same for your transactionmanager. I have the full code at my home laptop, will post the code later today.

Comment: If you're using a real Java EE server, just use EJB. If you're using a barebones servletcontainer like Tomcat, use Spring or consider migrating to TomEE so you can use EJB (and JPA instead of legacy Hibernate). Is this Q&A helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/18369356

Comment: @BalusC Using EJB to simplify a small part of code is over engineering in my opinion. EJB is for managers to tell stories to customers about business logic (I really hate this term).

Comment: user3509208, thank you :)  i am waiting. But if i use  Session s = this.session.getCurrentSession(); I anyway must write session.beginTransaction();
and session.getTransaction().commit();, right?

Comment: @v.ladynev: still hanging in J2EE era? It's since Java EE 5 just matter of only one annotation in order to reduce the entire method to an oneliner (on contrary to Spring, no single line of XML is necessary too).

Comment: @BalusC Yeah. I have an negative experience with EJB 2.1. So I try to don't use It at all :) And I think real life is more complex than a gigantic business method  with automatic transaction management :)

Comment: EJB2 died a decade ago. Try not spreading the decade-old bad experience then. This only misinforms starters.

Comment: @BalusC May be, you are right. A problem is not only with specifications, but with implementations too. For an example, we can have a lot of problems with  JEE implementation of some versions of WebSphere.